# Read layer symbology class color with ArcPy

Tags: raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, symbology

I am using ArcPy within ArcGIS 10.1 and attempting to read symbology from a *.lyr file created by a raster dataset within ArcMap.  My goal is to be able read out the RGB (color) values assigned to the class breaks on the dataset.
It’s seems easy enough to get the lyr file into an object with:

```
    lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:/.../ReadLyrFileSymbology/conus_foresttype6.img.lyr")
```

However, after that I am unable to find the method or property to get symbology color (RGB) on a layer.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

arcpy has access to class breaks, but not to renderers. Renderers are what set the color in symbology. You need to use ArcObjects to access renderers.

Answer (score 0):

If the class breaks were derived from the rasters rgb values, you might use arcpy.GetCellValue_management tool with the features centroid against the original raster?

[Saving polygon symbology as RGB values in the attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126340/27780)