# arcpy: read color value of shapefile loaded in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcpy, symbology, color

I've got various polyline shapefiles loaded in ArcGIS, each using the default line style with different colors. For a python addin I'm working on I would like to use arcpy to read the RGB value of these colors. Would that be possible?

I noticed this question: [Read layer symbology class color with ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71352/read-layer-symbology-class-color-with-arcpy)
But it deals with raster layers and therefore I assume my question is not a duplicate (please let me know if this is still the case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is as of ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1. It could change in the future since `arcpy.mapping` is constantly evolving.

If you are using default line styles, then your `layer.symbologyType` should be equal to `u'OTHER'`.

There is no way through `arcpy` or `arcpy.mapping` to access the symbology properties for a layer with `u'OTHER'` symbology. You should get a result of "NameError: The attribute 'symbology' is not supported on this instance of Layer" when trying to access the `symbology` attribute for that layer.

Even if the symbology was one of the types supported by `arcpy.mapping`, none of the supported types currently supports reading the color values of individual symbols.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's not possible. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: There is another option, but I am not sure you want to go this deep. You could construct a wrapper around ISymbologyControl http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/d/001600000324000000.htm using something like Iron Python (http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) or Python for .Net (http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html). Or you can go the C++ route (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#/ISymbologyControl_Interface/000600000324000000/) with something like this https://github.com/arcpy/arcpy-cpp-interop

Comment: I understand how that could work yes. But it would indeed go a bit too deep. Thanks for mentioning the links and this idea though, it might come in handy sometime!